# Find first 3 words in string as3

Tags: string, actionscript-3, substring

I want to execute a Private Message Function like this:

```
    var a = "/pm John Hello John! this is a private message";

    if(a.indexOf("/pm") >= 0){
        //It contains the String!
            trace("Contains /pm");
            sendPM(toWho, Msg);
        }
        else{
         sendPublicMsg();
}
```

- Detect if `/pm` is in the string,
- Call a function...

  - Using the second word (`John`)
  - Also using third part of the string (`Hello John! this is a private message`).

Comment: One of the many ways, but not the most efficient I'm sure: `var splitted:Array = a.split(" "); if(splitted[0] == "/pm"){ sendPM(splitted[1], a.replace(splitted[0] + " " +splitted[1],""));}`

Comment: @kaarto please add your above comment as Answer since it's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the many ways:

```
var a = "/pm John Hello John! this is a private message";
var splitted:Array = a.split(" "); 

if(splitted[0] == "/pm"){ 
    sendPM(splitted[1], a.replace(splitted[0] + " " +splitted[1],""));
}
```

Advantage over `indexOf` here is that now you can use `/pm` in the actual message if you need f.ex. to teach John how to use this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Another one of the many ways of resolving this is by using regular expressions:

```
var a:String = "/pm John Hello John! this is a private message";
var privateMessagePattern:RegExp = /(\/pm) (\w+) (.*)/;
if(a.search(privateMessagePattern) == 0) {
    var aMessage:Array = a.match(privateMessagePattern);
    var recipient:String = aMessage[2];
    var message:String = aMessage[3];
    sendPM(recipient, message);
} else {
    sendPublicMsg();
}
```

The **aMessage** Array, from the above code, will contain 4 elements (1st one is the original String and the next elements are the 3 groups defined by the **privateMessagePattern** RegExp. If the RegExp doesn't match the Array will be null, also the index returned by the search method will be -1.